# Routing Flask HTML table entires to individual SQL queries

Tags: flask, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask app that currently takes a user's search term from a form, and routes them to a new page with the SQL query results. On this page, I have an HTML table generated as follows:

```
<tbody>
    {% for row in result %}
        <tr>
        <td><a href={{NEW_QUERY_FUNC}} # problem here, described below
        {{row[0]}} 
        </a></td>
        <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
        <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

I have tried all sorts of strange things, but can't seem to figure out the following functionality:

I would like the user to be able to click that entry in the table, which will take them to a new page with further info. For example, if the table entry is 'Joe', they should be able to click that and be routed to a new page with Joe's phone number and address.

One of the main problems I'm having is figuring out how to get the actual value of that row to use for my query. How do I know that the name that the user clicks on is 'Joe', so I can run a query for the rest of Joe's details? Once I get that, how would I pass that argument to `app.py`? I was thinking I could turn each table row into a form? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would just make the name a link.
Assuming you have a list of user objects, that have a name attribute and a url attribute, the below snippet will create a link for each user, with their name being the link text. The user objects can just as easily be dictionaries, tuples, or whatever; just change the way the name and url are extracted

As an example:

```
<body>
{% for u in users %}
    <a href={{ u.url }}>{{ u.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This sounds like a good approach, I'll try it out in a bit. Only thing is I haven't actually made any models, I've been doing raw sql queries (SELECT * FROM ...), any idea if there's a way to make this work that way?